# How do I sort a list of strings by alphabetical order and length in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I tried to sort Linux block device used by `ansible_facts`.

I want to sort by alphabetical order and length.

**Expected result**

```
sda, sdb ,sdc, ..., sdaa, sdab, ..., sdbb
```

**Current result**

```
sda, sdaa, sdab, sdac ..., sdb, sdb, sdba, sdbb, sdbc, ...
```

How can I sort `sdaa` device after `sdz` device?

```yaml
- name: test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    - device: [sda,sdab,sdac,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde,sdf,sdg,sdh,sdi,sdj,sdk,sdl,sdm,sdn,sdo,sdp,sdq,sdr,sds,sdt,sdu,sdv,sdw,sdx,sdy,sdz,sdaa]

  tasks:
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ device | sort }}"
```

The result is

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "sda",
        "sdaa",
        "sdab",
        "sdac",
        "sdb",
        "sdc",
        "sdd",
        "sde",
        "sdf",
        "sdg",
        "sdh",
        "sdi",
        "sdj",
        "sdk",
        "sdl",
        "sdm",
        "sdn",
        "sdo",
        "sdp",
        "sdq",
        "sdr",
        "sds",
        "sdt",
        "sdu",
        "sdv",
        "sdw",
        "sdx",
        "sdy",
        "sdz"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be sorted this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten lists sorted by the length of the items. Create the below list of lists

```yaml
    dmin: "{{ device|map('length')|min }}"
    dmax: "{{ device|map('length')|max }}"

    device_sorted_lists: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for len in range(dmin|int, dmax|int + 1) %}
      {% set regex='^.{' ~ len ~ '}$' %}
      - {{ device|select('regex', regex)|sort }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

Flatten the lists

```yaml
  device_sorted: "{{ device_sorted_lists|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  device_sorted:
  - sda
  - sdb
  - sdc
  - sdd
  - sde
  - sdf
  - sdg
  - sdh
  - sdi
  - sdj
  - sdk
  - sdl
  - sdm
  - sdn
  - sdo
  - sdp
  - sdq
  - sdr
  - sds
  - sdt
  - sdu
  - sdv
  - sdw
  - sdx
  - sdy
  - sdz
  - sdaa
  - sdab
  - sdac
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    device: [sda,sdab,sdac,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde,sdf,sdg,sdh,sdi,sdj,sdk,sdl,sdm,sdn,sdo,sdp,sdq,sdr,sds,sdt,sdu,sdv,sdw,sdx,sdy,sdz,sdaa]

    dmin: "{{ device|map('length')|min }}"
    dmax: "{{ device|map('length')|max }}"

    device_sorted_lists: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for len in range(dmin|int, dmax|int + 1) %}
      {% set regex='^.{' ~ len ~ '}$' %}
      - {{ device|select('regex', regex)|sort }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    device_sorted: "{{ device_sorted_lists|flatten }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: device_sorted_lists

    - debug:
        var: device_sorted
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might be a start of a solution:

```py
{% set devices_with_length = [] %}
{% for dev in devices %}
  {{ devices_with_length.append(
     {"length": dev | length, 
      "name": dev}
    ) | default("", True) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ devices_with_length | sort(attribute="length") | map(attribute="name") | list }}
```

Which will produce the following output:

```yaml
[sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, sde, sdf, sdg, sdh, sdi, sdj, sdk, sdl, sdm, sdn, sdo, sdp, sdq, sdr, sds, sdt, sdu, sdv, sdw, sdx, sdy, sdz, sdab, sdac, sdaa]
```

When fed with the following input:

```yaml
devices: [sda,sdab,sdac,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde,sdf,sdg,sdh,sdi,sdj,sdk,sdl,sdm,sdn,sdo,sdp,sdq,sdr,sds,sdt,sdu,sdv,sdw,sdx,sdy,sdz,sdaa]
```

To have sdaa appear directly after sdz would probably involve creating a custom sort algorithm in jinja, which I would not recommend.

Comment: "_To have `sdaa` appear directly after sdz would probably involve creating a Custom Filter sort algorithm in Jinja2_",  Or just pre-sort the list `devices` via `devices | sort` and feed that to your example ...

Comment: @U880D oh yeah, that might work, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

Yet an other way to get the same result. In short:

- Create a list of (<length>, <name>) tuples
- Sort that list by length
- Group entries by length
- Extracts names only in each compartment, sort by name and flatten the result

This is the playbook I used (with debug you can turn on with `-v` to inspect intermediate steps):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    device_list: [
      "sda",
      "sdaa",
      "sdab",
      "sdac",
      "sdb",
      "sdc",
      "sdd",
      "sde",
      "sdf",
      "sdg",
      "sdh",
      "sdi",
      "sdj",
      "sdk",
      "sdl",
      "sdm",
      "sdn",
      "sdo",
      "sdp",
      "sdq",
      "sdr",
      "sds",
      "sdt",
      "sdu",
      "sdv",
      "sdw",
      "sdx",
      "sdy",
      "sdz"
    ]

    device_names_length: "{{ device_list | map('length') }}"

    device_by_length: "{{ device_names_length | zip(device_list) | groupby(0) | sort(0) }}"

    device_sorted: "{{ device_by_length | map(attribute=1) | map('map', attribute=1) | map('sort') | flatten }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show initial device list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: device_list
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show calculated names length
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: device_names_length
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show device sorted and grouped by name length
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: device_by_length
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show final sorted list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: device_sorted
```

Running the playbook (without verbosity) gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show initial device list] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show calculated names length] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show device sorted and grouped by name length] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show final sorted list] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "device_sorted": [
        "sda",
        "sdb",
        "sdc",
        "sdd",
        "sde",
        "sdf",
        "sdg",
        "sdh",
        "sdi",
        "sdj",
        "sdk",
        "sdl",
        "sdm",
        "sdn",
        "sdo",
        "sdp",
        "sdq",
        "sdr",
        "sds",
        "sdt",
        "sdu",
        "sdv",
        "sdw",
        "sdx",
        "sdy",
        "sdz",
        "sdaa",
        "sdab",
        "sdac"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```